# nice effect / widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across this amazing thing I want to do the same on my website. Its from [this link](http://maps.ovi.com) , the magics happens when you click on [this](http://i48.tinypic.com/4ihgmt.png) button, does anyone knows how this can be done, or what is this effect / widget called so I can google for potentially solutions. thank you

*Details from viewing site:*

Clicking the [image]
 (Left Arrow Image) causes the left panel to collapse to a minimal state (at which point the arrow changes direction and the process can be reversed)

**UPDATE:** How to position Left Arrow Image in that same place as in the website above, can I get some css hints ? thank you

**UPDATE 2** : I'm currently using prototype for several functionalities on my website. thx

Comment: The button image you linked to doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the edit scunliffe

Comment: Are you using any JS frameworks at the moment? e.g. jQuery, mootools, etc.  If so, please specify as it would help us provide the most useful solution.

Comment: Actually, the effect is done very badly. They let the text get squished like an unhappy slice of meat in a cruelly tight sandwich. They should keep the text container's width fixed and animate the width of the text container's container (whoa) having set this second container's "overflow" property to "hidden".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they did it using [mootools](http://mootools.net/), but I think it's called a "[slide](http://demos.mootools.net/Fx.Slide)" effect, and almost every javascript framework (prototype using [scriptacouls](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/combination-effects-demo), [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide), etc.) has support to do that effect, and similar ones.

Comment: It's not a slide, they are animating the width.

Answer (score 0):

you can [google for feedback widget](http://www.google.com/search?q=feedback+widget) and come up with a variety of those .. also not incredibly difficult to build with [jQuery's animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) function ..

Comment: I know about jquery animate is there something similar for prototype or ordinary javascript?