# Forcing windows resize to fire

Tags: javascript

I have problems with my layout, when I re-size window manually and restore it to normal everything is in the perfect place.

Is it possible to trick the browser and do something with JavaScript that would actually make the browser think that the page has been re-sized so that my layout looks as it should?

**UPDATE:**

Can I re-size and restore window so that user barely notices?

Comment: If your layout is broken and is fixed after a resize, you should fix the layout. What browser is this in? Can you post a link to a live example?

Comment: Unfortunately its on localhost, I don't have it online, the thing is that it  is fixed after a resize as you say ..

Comment: I think you should really look into how to fix the layout. Working around this using Javascript is shaky.

Comment: Its not the design issue design is fine , but after certain action the design looks ok only after resize. As I said below "The problem is following, I have left sidebar and central div , onclick I made it so that central div takes the its own space + left sidebar space, after that resize is needed to fix stuff back to normal "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with [Mootools](http://mootools.net) (which means it can be done without a framework as well), here's an example:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
 window.addEvent('resize', function() {
  alert('f');
 });
 (function() {
  window.fireEvent('resize');
 }).delay(3000);
});
```

3 seconds after the DOM-structure has loaded, the resize-event will be fired for the window-object.

**Edit;**

I have no clue how Mootools solves their fireEvent for the resize event. I tried Google, but found nada. You can of course resize the window manually, but this is really a hack:

```
function fireOnResizeEvent() {
 var width, height;

 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
  width  = document.body.offsetWidth;
  height = document.body.offsetHeight;
 } else {
  width  = window.outerWidth;
  height = window.outerHeight;
 }

 window.resizeTo(width - 1, height);
 window.resizeTo(width + 1, height);
}

window.onresize = function() {
 alert("Resized!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you bjorn.. I'm currently googling solution for ordinary javascrpt

Comment: Nothing yet, how bout if I resize/restore really fast is that possible?

Comment: Sorry Björn I had some other projects to attend to .. I guess its working .. I'll accept your answer for now (didn't have time to test it). thank you

Comment: I think BillyTom has the best answer.  We could accept that answer or integrate that answer into this one.

Comment: I agree @BillyTom has the best answer. However to answer the question of how mootools does it, they simply store handles to all the event callbacks, and when you "refireEvent" it directly calls the function. See: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/2f0aee54c40525e4261b556bc6ed2a12a619db73/Source/Element/Element.Event.js#L103

Answer (score 75):

Since then a better solution has been posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18693617/2306587:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: Worth noting no support below ie11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Browser_compatibility

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#search=dispatchEvent it should work for IE 9+. However `window.fireEvent()` should also work for IE 10 and under.

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't work in my IE11. Throws `Object doesn't support this action`

Answer (score 8):

You can resize the window like this...

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

And if you need to trigger the event handler, you can do that like this...

```
window.onresize();
```

Comment: hmm can I manually fire the onresize event while firing my event?

Comment: Just like it says in my answer: `window.onresize();`

Comment: `window.onresize()` is not working for me: `TypeError: Property 'onresize' of object [object global] is not a function`

Comment: From what @JoshStodola says, you can do this:

`window.onresize = function() {...};`

`$(document).ready( window.onresize() );`

Worked with JQuery 3 and Firefox 55.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the jQuery `resize()` method, like this:

```
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: Doesn't work or at least it doesn't appear to have any affect. Maybe under some conditions it does.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working solution:

```
if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
  // modern browsers
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
} else {
  // for IE and other old browsers
  // causes deprecation warning on modern browsers
  var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
  evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
  window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

toggle the display attribute on the areas that need to be redrawn. for example:

```
var toDraw = document.getElementById('redrawme');
toDraw.style.display = none;
toDraw.style.display = '';
```

I dont know whqt the result would be if you tried to do the entire body element as ive never tired it before.

What are you doing that you need to force a redraw?

Comment: Hmm the problem is following, I have left sidebar and central div , onclick I made it so that central div takes the its own space + left sidebar space, after that resize is needed to fix stuff back to normal

Comment: how are your columns laid out? its probably your layout that needs fixed as suggested above. personally id float them both left in side a wrapper with a clearfix on it and modify from there. Since theyd both be in document flow that should fix the issues youre having i would think.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html - Auto Method
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html - pseudo class method

Comment: Can you post the relvent parts of you layout and css?

Comment: I already did.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859559/trying-to-change-width-on-click

Comment: ok added a comment there will echo the same here: 

Given that content is floated isnt a percentage based width going to be calculated from the last parent element in the hierarchy that is given a hard width or if none its intrinsic width?

What happens if you give #contentholder a hard width in px/pt/cm or alternately use one of the former units in your dynmic width assignment for content?